# nth odd/even child elements h3

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a html page setup like so

```
<div class="row row-venue">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>Venue 1</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-venue">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>Venue 2</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

All I want to do is make every odd  h3 a different colour to every even. I have tried with the code below

```
div.row-venue div.col-venue h3:nth-of-type(odd){
  color:white;
}
div.row-venue div.col-venue h3:nth-of-type(even){
  color:black;
}
```

and even just tried

```
h3:nth-of-type(odd){
  color:white;
}

h3:nth-of-type(even){
  color:black;
}
```

I just cant seem to get my head around it, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense now, never used it previous just use to hardcode it, this will save me a lot of time. Appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<h3>` is always the first child of `<div class="col-sm-12">`. Because the counting is zero base - first child = even, so the even rule that you defined applies to all `<h3>` elements.

To get what you ask, you need to find the nth child between the `<div class="row row-venue">` items:

```css
.row-venue:nth-child(odd) h3 {
    color: white;
}
.row-venue:nth-child(even) h3 {
    color: black;
}
```

If your divs are mixed with other elements, use `:nth-of-type` instead of `:nth-child`.

Comment: OP was using `:nth-of-type` not `:nth-child`, not sure what the clarification is for. Did you flip flop the two by accident?

Comment: He said that he "and even just tried" :nth-of-type as a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is targeting odd/even `<h3>` tags within a `.col-venue` element, which I don't see in your markup. Even if `.col-venue` was in your markup It would only be targeting H3s within it - [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvezzrnq/1/).

You need to control the styling from a higher level in the markup, see below.

```html
<div class="row row-venue">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>Venue 1</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-venue">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>Venue 2</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.row-venue:nth-of-type(odd) h3 {
    color: red;
}
.row-venue:nth-of-type(even) h3 {
    color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvezzrnq/

With the above CSS selectors you are targeting odd and even `.row-venue` elements and then drilling down to the h3.