# How make margins between divs with a percentage width?

Tags: css, margin

I want four columns with `width: 25%;` of the page. Between the columns there should be a 10px margin (i.e. `margin-right: 10px;`). The `last:child` statement (for `margin-right: 0px;` doesn't work due to the hierarchy.

How do I solve this?

Thanks!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
article {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 25%;
}
.content:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.top {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="top">
        Top
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="top">
        Top
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="top">
        Top
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="top">
        Top
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you have `width: 25%;` you will not have even `1px` for left or right margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the :last-child on the parent. See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967232/nth-odd-even-child-elements-h3/31967366#31967366).

```
article:last-child > .content {
margin-right: 0;
}
```

As @Shehary noted, you won't have enough space for margins, as .container is defined as 25%, and you have four = 100%.

To circumvent that, you'll have to remove the total margins out of each .content. There are only 3 margin-right, as the last is 0, so 3 * 10 = 30. 30 / 4 = 7.5. Let's round it up to 8, as fractions might cause other annoying rendering problems,

Which means that you should calc(25% - 8px) for the width ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6twrdorz/3)):

```
.content {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: calc(25% - 8px); /** width with margin allowance **/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`flexbox` can do that

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space=between;
}
article {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
article:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.content {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  height: 200px;
}
.top {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="top">Top</div>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="top">Top</div>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="top">Top</div>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="top">Top</div>
  </div>
</article>
```